# tips for ASP.net MVC And Data Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I need your opinion on which is better. In an ASP.net MVC project, is it recommended to have one DataModel for my whole database or one for each table in my database?

Note : I'm using EF dataFirst Model with a oracle database.

Comment: Are you able to clean up the grammar of your question? I'm having trouble understanding it. Also, try not to ask too open-ended, subjective questions. Try to ask a question that has an answer and that solves a direct problem.

Comment: sorry I'm got some trouble with grammar and english. I updated my post  take look. thanks

Comment: Do you perhaps mean data context for entity framework, related objects should be included in the same data context. One per table is not required

Comment: Thanx @MikeBeeler also when I update my database I have to update also my DataContext so what's the best way to do that ?

Comment: entity framework power tools to reverse engineer your database and generate the dbset/mappings for each table (all of the tables are included) and you may need to remove some of them from the generated code but are all in one context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lolz thats a nice question. I think you are new to MVC and EF.
Use one DataModel for the whole Database. Entity Frame work supports Oracle databse.
One DbContext represents one database. But, you can have mutliple databse in your project. So, you will have their respective DbContext's.

there are three approch to work with entity framework :

- Model First
- Data First
- Code First

Configuring and using different approches are explained here 
https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/different-approaches-of-entity-framework/

But, I personally prefer Database First.

If you want to learn more abt ASP.NET MVC with EF look here, Its with Data First 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/695850/Complete-CRUD-Operations-in-MVC

Comment: Thank's but unfortunly `EF code First` is not supported by Oracle Database Provider.

Comment: @Chlebta Dude, thanks. You updated lil bit of my knowledge :)

Comment: Can'I got you'r mail ?